# like Gauss-Chebyshev integration formula using Lagrange polynomials

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, interpolation

Suppose that $L_k(x)$ is Lagrange Interpolation Polynomial for points $x=1,0,-1$. How to show that:
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=\sum_{k=-1}^1C_kf(k)+E$$
where $C_k=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{L_k(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$.

Comment: Let $\displaystyle E = \int_{-1}^{1}\frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx - \sum_{k=-1}^1C_kf(k)$. Done.

Comment: but why? please show a direct way.